# Common divisors of integers

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

So I had this question:

Find the integers $n,a,b \in \mathbb Z$ such that $n|ab$ but $n$ does not divide $a$ or $b$.

So one solution was $n=4,a=b=2$.

I was just wondering, is this the only format of solution possible to a scenario such as this? i.e this can only be true iff:

1) $ a=b$

2) $n>a=b$

Comment: No, $n=9, a=3, b=6$.

Comment: That property of $n$ characterizes the primes: if $n$ is not prime, it is possible that $n$ divides $ab$ without dividing either of $a$ or $b$; but if $n$ is prime, then $n$ divides $ab$ if and only if it divides $a$ or $b$. That is in fact the definition of a prime number.

Comment: Ahhh, I see, I believe I misunderstood the notation. So when saying $9|18$ this is equivalent to saying $18/9$ and not $9/18$ ?

Comment: No, it is saying "9 divides 18" - it says nothing about the quotient and it has nothing to do with either fraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need $n$ to be composite and for its factors to be split between $a$ and $b$.  You can have $n=6, a=8, b=9$, for example.  Frequently you will have $a,b \gt n$.  You could also have $n=6, a=56,b=93$.  Don't try to make a list, it is infinite.